# Is Cain having memory trouble?

Tags: diablo-iii

On act 1, when you find the stranger (Tyrael) in the crater, right after the Skeleton King, you bring him back to town and speak to Cain. Cain seems to not recognize him, but how is it possible, since in Diablo 2 act 4 theyre standing side by side and if I'm correct Cain knows Tyrael personally... Is this a game mistake?

Comment: Go easy on the poor guy... [he's not exactly a Spring chicken!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67404/how-much-time-passed-between-diablo-ii-and-diablo-iii)

Answer (score 16):

Human Tyrael really looks nothing like Angel Tyrael.  They do have the same voice, but there's no way you could tell that it's the same guy just by looking at them.  The old Tyrael had a completely dark face, you could not see it.

[image: Old Tyrael]
[image: New Tyrael]

Comment: Not to mention, noone would have any idea what his race was based on Angel Tyrael

Comment: Also, Cain says that he suspected the Stranger is Tyrael as he dies. His reasons for not disclosing his suspicions sooner are his own however.

Comment: Even earlier, Cain says that he thinks the sword will restore the Stranger's memories. This isn't just a paper-thin reason for a quest to go find the sword fragments. He must know something he's not telling us.

Comment: I believe in the cutscene where Tyrael changes to his human form it shows his head essentially materializing, kinda showing he never had it before and hence no one's really gonna recognize him.

Answer (score 13):

Cain does have memory problems. See how many bags he has lost, with his working notes, all around the world.

Comment: Good point! Seems the old coot could barely finish writing a page before losing his satchel!

Comment: Not just pages; he was **rich** but forgot flawless emeralds in satchels also. Or maybe it was meant to be a present for little Leah, and she had to settle for a Horadric scroll instead

Comment: I am almost wondering if this is a bug... I mean... If there was one "Cain's satchel" i could understand... But the shear number of them almost makes me think that they were supposed to be called just "Bags" or something, but all of them inherited the name of Cain's satchel per mistake.

Comment: But each one contains something directly related to Deckard Cain (at least the first time you find it).  Why would you find one of Deckard Cain's journals in something named Bags?  Perhaps they should stop saying Cain's satchel after the journal entry is already found, but that's the obvious name for those that do contain notes.  Fortunately it seems that he was rich enough to keep replacing the stupid things.